# Object must be an instance or subtype of type in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm learning django from thedjangobook and there is an example at class based views that it's in the django documentations aswell, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#performing-extra-work), my problem is that i'm getting an error when i'm trying to run this.

It is supposed to keep track of the last time anybody looked at an
author:

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    salutation = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, verbose_name='e-mail')
    headshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='author_headshots', null=True, blank=True)
    last_accessed = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^authors/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.AuthorDetailView.as_view(), name='AuthorDetailView'),
]
```

views.py

```
class AuthorDetailView(DetailView):

    def get_object(self, queryset=Author.objects.all()):
        # Call the superclass
        object_1 = super(Author, self).get_object()

        # Record the last accesed date
        object_1.last_accessed = timezone.now()
        object_1.save()

        # Return the object
        return object_1
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/Documents/Proiecte/Django/Django_tutorial/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/alex/Documents/Proiecte/Django/Django_tutorial/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/alex/Documents/Proiecte/Django/Django_tutorial/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/Documents/Proiecte/Django/Django_tutorial/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/Documents/Proiecte/Django/Django_tutorial/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/Documents/Proiecte/Django/Django_tutorial/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py", line 115, in get
    self.object = self.get_object()
  File "/home/alex/Documents/Proiecte/Django/Django_tutorial/mysite/books/views.py", line 179, in get_object
    object_1 = super(Author, self).get_object()
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `get_object` method is trying to call super, but you need to pass in the current class name rather than the model name

```
    object_1 = super(Author, self).get_object()
```

should be either

```
    object_1 = super(AuthorDetailView, self).get_object()
    object_1 = super().get_object()  # The args can be omitted for Python 3
```

Comment: omg i can't believe i didn't see that, and i've done it many time, just a mistake now, the program automatically completed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Any ideea how it should been written in template? They don't offer an example for template.

Comment: @NitaAlexandru - This isn't something you should be doing in the template